# Excel VBA: ListBox-UserForm Variable creation issue

Tags: vba, excel

Checked other similar questions on other websites, but could not find a solution.

I am trying to generate variables from the contents of a listbox-userform. The contents in the list are the names of workbooks. The first piece of code shows you how I generate the contents of the list for your reference. The second piece of code is the one with the issue.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        With ListBox1
            .AddItem (wb.Name)
        End With
    Next wb
lbl_Exit:
End Sub
```

I am getting a `Object Required` error on the For Each line below. This piece of code resides in the `Userform`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim MainBook As Workbook
    Dim ListBox1 As ListBox

    For Each Item In ListBox1
        If Item.Name Like "Aggregate" Then
            Item.Select
            Set MainBook = Selection
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note**: I read that `Item` is a property of a ListBox which is where I got that from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        With ListBox1
           .AddItem (wb.Name)
        End With
    Next wb
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim MainBook As Workbook, i as Long

    For i = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount -1)
        If ListBox1.List(i) Like "Aggregate" Then
            Set MainBook = Workbooks(ListBox1.List(i))
            MainBook.Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like that works, thanks. But with the new variable MainBook, am I free to reference it in my code within the module, or is there something special I need to do to have it transfer from the UserForm to the Module?

Comment: Yes you can reference it, provided you move `Dim MainBook As Workbook` to the very top :) Else you will only be able to work with it in the `CommandButton2_Click` procedure.